# Change Robject into Python

Tags: python, rpy2

Assuming I have a variable named `test` which has the following datatype and value:

```
<rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector object at 0x000001F1B51116C0> [RTYPES.REALSXP]
R classes: ('numeric',)
[0.916667]
```

How do I change it into python variable such that `test` has a value of 0.916667 ?

I tried to do `robjects.conversion.py2rpy(test)`, but it is not working, so I assume I did it wrongly... I tried searching the web and documentation but still cannot find the answer.

Thank you very much for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem. I can easily obtain the answer through

```
test = test[0]
```

However, I'm unsure if the same thing would work if I'm converting from R vector to Python vector.